# Using the central limit theorem on a binomial random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, central-limit-theorem

I need to show that the limit as n goes to infinity of $P(X_n \geq \frac{n}{2})$ is 1/2 if the expected value is equal to 1. The random variables are binomially partitioned but it's not given that they are independent.

This would be straightforward if $X_n$ were less than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$, but since it isn't I think I would need to use Markov's inequality somewhere to get an estimate. A short explanation or hint on how to strategize would suffice.

Comment: Binomial distributions have 2 parameters. Is $n$ related to one of them, or is $\forall n, E[X_n]=1$ the only condition?

Comment: That's the only condition.

Answer (score 1):

$X_n\sim B(m_n,p_n)$ with $m_np_n=1$. $P(X_n\geq \frac n 2)\leq 4\frac {EX_n^{2}}{n^{2}}=4\frac {m_np_n(1-p_n)+(m_np_n)^{2}} {n^{2}}=4\frac {2-p_n}{n^{2}} \to 0$.

Comment: Since I'm still new to this, could you explain how this connects to the central limit theorem and finding out that the limit is 1/2?

Comment: The limit is $0$, not $1/2$. So the question is wrong and CLT cannot be used. @No_Bass

Comment: I see where I went wrong. The limit should be 1 with $p_n$ = 1, as in the $p_n$ in the expected value $m_np_n$. Apologies.

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: Changing the question long after an answer has appeared it not proper. You should ask a separate question and restore this to the original form. @No_Bass

Comment: I've changed it back.